# Acronyms with Sphinx search engine

Tags: mysql, search, text, sphinx, full-text-search

how can i index acronyms like 'm.i.a.'? when i search for 'mia', i get results for 'mia' and not 'm.i.a.'. when i search for 'm.i.a.', i get nothing at all.

edit:

solution looks roughly like: `ignore_chars = -, .`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could add '.' to your ignored character list:
http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-ignore-chars

or you could maybe add m.i.a. > mia as a wordform:
http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms